# getting lot of 502 errors from gcm servers

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I am using gcm json protocol to send notifications. Somrtimes for certain period of time gcm endpoints are responding with 502 error code.

Is there a status dashboard for gcm service api ?

And

What could be reason of these 502 error codes ?